# Interview Challenge: Write a function to test if a string is a palindrome

Tags: php, string, function, recursion, palindrome

I had an interview yesterday for a *Senior Software Developer* role. I can't remember the question very well, but I try to write it as much as I remember.

**Question:**

Write a function that takes a string as the input and return true if traversed, false if not.

**Requirements**: (as much as I remember)

- There is only one input type: string.
- The string parameter must be passed by reference.
- No new variables should be declared within the function -- he meant that if the parameter is called `$str`, then manipulation should only be done on that. He didn't like me using a second variable to set `$reverseStr` etc.
- No looping every character in the string, he specifically said not to loop thru every character in the string.
- No built-in PHP functions could be used; I think he was fine with `strlen()`.

**My Answer:** (nope he didn't like it)

```
$str = 'this is testing';
$length = strlen($str);
$reverseStr = '';
for($i=$length-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
 $reverseStr .= $str[$i];
}
```

While this does the job somewhat, he didn't like me to go through every character to get `$reverseStr`. I am guessing I needed to think about a recursive solution get the last character of the string and index etc., but I am thinking about these as I am writing this, too late!

What you guys thinking?

Comment: While I understand it violates a rule, be aware that PHP has [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php).

Comment: Are you supposed to reverse the string, or just to check if it is a palindrome? The function name suggests the former, but its contents suggest the latter.

Comment: Yeah because you always get real world requirements like `no built in function can be used`.

Comment: @MrCode This task is clearly intended to test the algorithmic approach of the interviewee. It is not intended as a real-life scenario, and it seems that it clearly did its job, as the OP showed an extrmely literal approach, which is not really suitable for a senior developer position.

Comment: No built in function ???? Does that include loops ?

Comment: @Baba a loop is not a function.

Comment: You violated the rule against using a variable in the function.

Comment: @Yoshi But the rules specifically said "no looping over every character".

Comment: What exactly was the question/exercise, I didn't get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the question isn't clear at all.. but if you want to check if the string is a palindrome:

```
function is_palindrome ($str){
    if(strlen($str)==0){return true;}
    if($str[0]==$str[strlen($str)-1]){
        return true and is_palindrome(substr($str, 1, strlen($str)-2));
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `strlen` is in built PHP function

Comment: @Baba True, but in the OP he mentions the interviewer was fine with use of strlen. Also, a requirement was to pass `$str` by reference which this answer seems to have missed...will upvote if that is fixed.

Comment: yeah but it's a common one, also the OP said it was fine to use it.

Comment: I think we need to set realistic bounds. Unless you're planning to re-write all the basic essentials needed for string manipulation and transverse the use of `strlen` should be expected. If this was an interview it'd be something you'd clarify.

Comment: about the reference, you are totally right! I missed that part, so this answer wouldn't work since it would destroy the string :p

Comment: Then the question is not really clear .. so many conflicting statement

Comment: The reference requirement suggests that the string and bounds should be passed, but that conflicts with the requirement to only take one argument. Are optional arguments allowed -- the initial call would use the defaults, but recursive calls would pass them.

Comment: @lanzz yes it basically asking if it's a palindrome.

Comment: @Mansfield how can you say `No Built-in PHP function can be used` then be ok with `strlen` ???

Comment: @Baba I don't know. I'm not the interviewer. But the exception of strlen seems fairly clear from the question.

Comment: you know how there are functions like strrev, strcompare and such, they never want you to use them in an interview, to test your problem solving skills

Comment: @Barmar: Just curious - why do bounds need to be passed separately?

Comment: @Naryl yes your solution seems to be killing the string, this is someewhat what I was trying on my own, any more ideas?

Comment: @Mansfield Does PHP allow you to create substring references?

Comment: anybody knows a good reference for interview questions?

Why o why, STRING MANIPULATION IS THE ONLY thing they ask i don't know

Comment: @vknyvz as far as I know in interviews they are more insterested in your general knowledge about programing. They don't want to check if you know all php functions, google is there for that. The only way to adquire that is to practice and get experience. Also I have seen many interview questions where recursion is the answer, they just love it :p

Answer (score 0):

I think this works. untested. Although it does have internal variables.

```
    function is_palindrome( &$str )
    {
        $i = $j = 0;
        while( isset( $str[++$j] ) ) {};

        while( $i < --$j )
        {
            if( $str[$i++] !== $str[$j] )
                return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: Did you test this ? I think you should

Comment: @Matt Wilson  I can't run this also trying to understand what you did in the reverse()

Comment: to all he said the reason why we don't want any extra variable is because it _saves memory_ said the interviewer

so far I like @Naryl 's fix on this

Comment: I gave up on the reverse, I was trying to adapt a C version that does work, but php wouldnt have it

Comment: @vknyvz "because it saves memory said the interviewer" on which you responded: WTF do you care about memory use *and* use PHP <- that would have been *the* answer.

Answer (score 0):

So he said "no looping through every character", but he didn't say anything about looping through *half* of them? [evil laugh]

```
function is_palindrome(&$str) {
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str) / 2; $i++) {
        if ($str[$i] != $str[strlen($str)-1-$i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

He said no variable within the function for manipulating `$str`, but surely an iterator is fine? (well, except the "no looping" rule...)

```
is_palindrome('abcdcba'); // odd length, returns true
is_palindrome('abcddcba'); // even length, returns true
is_palindrome('abc'); // not a palindrome, returns false
```

I know, I know, it's squeezing by the letter of the requirements and not the spirit of them.

Comment: my first answer was something like this, he didn't like it for the fact that I used _for_

Answer (score 0):

### How do you satisfy the brief?

- I interpret the "no looping over all of the characters" to be a hint to use recursion without actually saying the word "recursion" in the description. (I can't think of another way of processing a variable-length string as prescribed without using some kind of looping construct/function.)
- The requirement to pass the string in by reference is probably in place to prevent you from passing the input string as `substr($str, 1, -1)` in the recursive call. This will indicate to the interviewer that you know how to identify and overcome such a programmatical constraint.
- The requirement to not declare any new variables in the function body is tedious. It will require the call of `strlen()` multiple times instead of caching it the first time, but okay.  Satisfying this rule and the pass by reference rule will mean that the subsequent "middle substrings" will need to overwrite the input string before being passed into the recursive call.
- I interpret the "no built-in functions" to mean: only use the most basic, native string measuring and cutting functions (no regex or "heavier"/"convenient" processing manipulations). Otherwise, interviewees might try to cut the string at its midpoint, call `strrev()` (which is a loop under the hood) and compare the two halves.

These very limiting rules simplify the job of the interviewer. Because there are very few ways to accomplish this AND fully satisfy the brief, they will be able to compare the output of multiple candidates in an "oranges to oranges" fashion.

This could be a favorable solution: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AcjTr))

```
function isPalindrome(string &$str): bool
{
    if (strlen($str) <= 1) {
        return true; // reached the middle of the palindrome successfully
    }
    if ($str[0] !== $str[strlen($str) - 1]) {
        return false; // outermost characters are not identical, halt processing
    }
    $str = substr($str, 1, -1); // remove outermost characters
    return (__FUNCTION__)($str); // traverse deeper and bubble outcome to top level
}
```

### What intangibles might the interviewer observe?

Interviews are seldom binary "pass/fail" based on task output.  You might not write a working script, or you might not satisfy all of the requirements. This doesn't mean that you will be excluded from the role. A skilful interviewer will be observing micro-behaviors, attitude, and cultural fit.

- How did you react upon being presented the coding challenge?

  - Did you pump your arm and say: "Yes, a recursion challenge! Let's go!"
  - Did you stoically grab your tools and start ticking away at the keyboard?
  - Did you audibly grumble something like: "Ugh, another interview with a completely unrealistic set of constraints."
  - Did you frankly say: "I think you want recursion, but to be honest I am garbage at recursive tasks. Do you have another challenge?"
  - Did you wipe your forehead, stare blankly at the task paper, and re-read the requirements for 5 minutes in the hope that a miraculous epiphany would arrive?
  - Did you take action before seeking clarifications so that you can compile a full set of questions and only ask 1 batch of questions?
  - Did you ask a myriad of questions before touching the keyboard?

    - Are you seeking a recursive function?
    - ...is there a specific whitelist or blacklist of native functions?
    - ...why can't I use loops?
    - ...can you tell me if the input is only letters?
    - ...will those letters always be lowercase?
    - ...might there be multibyte characters?
    - ...might an empty string be passed in?
    - ...if an empty string is possible, should it [return false](https://3v4l.org/TiNa3)?
    - ...if non-letters might be encountered, should they be sanitized in advance?
    - ...do you prefer ternary expressions?
    - ...do you prefer multiple `return`s in a single function?
    - ...should I optimize the script with a particular metric in mind (memory, time complexity, number of recursive calls)?
    - ...would you allow a `preg_match()` call if I could demonstrate [a non-recursive function which implements a recursive regular expression](https://3v4l.org/TaKVS)? ([more concise](https://3v4l.org/FTuN3))
- When you communicate with someone, how do you express yourself?

  - Do you avoid technical speak and act hesitant when you use technical terms?
  - Do you seek out excuses to blend technical terms into conversation to demonstrate your vocabulary?
  - Do you use 15 words when 3 words will do?
  - Do you keep communication with other humans to an ABSOLUTE minimum?
- If you were unsuccessful...

  - Did you become confrontational about whether your solution should be acceptable?
  - Did you give up after a rather short period of effort?
  - Did you give up only after an exceedingly long period of effort?
  - Did you ask to take the assignment paper home or take photo of the task so that you could work on it more later?
- If you were successful...

  - After completing the task in less than 60 seconds, did you pick up your keyboard and blow it off like it was a smoking gun then smile smugly at the interviewer?
  - Did you proclaim: "I AM THE GOAT THAT ALL OTHER GOATS CALL 'SIR'!"?
  - Did you high five the interviewer, tell them that you enjoyed it, and ask for another?
  - Did you remain as expressionless as a corpse?
  - Did you say: "Phew, got lucky on that one."?
- If asked to explain your code, how comfortable and clear would you be in communicating the processes and your design choices?

These behaviors will be very exposing of your personality and will indicate a likelihood of gelling with the dev team and company culture.

### How can your code outshine other candidates'?

Observing your social/behavioral actions is one thing, depth of technical aptitude and attention to detail is another.

It might give you an edge over your competition if:

- You implement effective unit testing.
  If you only test positive strings, then they know that you cannot be trusted to write unit tests -- you only check if your code *can* work, not if it can be broken.
  If you generate obscure test strings that are not merely comprised of single-byte, lowercase letters, then this indicates that you are aware of real-world challenges.
  (In my snippet above, it is NOT written to correctly handle unicode characters, but it would be trivial to add `mb_` to the measuring and cutting functions to make it so.)
- You write PSR-compliant code.
  If you haven't memorized the majority of rules, it will show. It is a corollary to using functional, yet poor English grammar ("Ain't doin' too good, is ya?") A professional PHP developer needs to be very familiar with PSR. As a starting point, memorize [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) rules -- they will put you on the right track.
- You write concise, meaningful comments.
  Do you write DocBlock comments before the function signature or do you write inline comments?
  Do you verbosely explain every line or only lines where the intent isn't clear?

Finally, if you aren't sure what the interviewer would value... ASK THEM!